# Angular2 HTTP - Providing a non-empty HTTP content-type header *Safari*

Tags: http, angular, http-headers, dropbox

So I'm using the [Dropbox HTTP API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) with my Angular2 App. I can log in, authorise, and use the `list_folder` requests etc., this all works as expected.
But when I attempt to perform a simple post request to `files/download` I get an error saying I've provided a non-empty `content-type`:

```
Error in call to API function \"files/download\": You provided a non-empty HTTP \"Content-Type\" header (\"text/plain;charset=UTF-8\").
```

This is my current code - I've tried it many different ways and I'm not setting the `content-type` anywhere.

```
let headers = new Headers();
let url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';

headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer <inserted-bearer-here>`);
headers.append("Dropbox-API-Arg", "{\"path\": \"/Documents/code/convert.js\"}");

console.log(headers);

// this is an RxJS observable which is subscribed to later in my code...
return this.http.post(url, null, { headers: headers });
```

The `content-type` is definitely not set since I log the headers to the console before sending them:

[image: Logged headers variable]

Anyone able to shed some light on this problem? I looked through other questions on SO and only found incorrectly set `content-type` fields etc., nothing where they weren't set and it wasn't working.

**-- Edit --**

This code works correctly in Chrome:

```
let headers = new Headers({
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.userData.bearer}`,
  'Dropbox-API-Arg': "{\"path\": \"/Documents/code/convert.js\"},
  'content-type': null
});
http.post(url, null, { headers: headers })
    .subsribe(...);
```

However, in Safari it seems that if the `Content-Type` is `null` it automatically appends `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

I can't seem to find a way to force-sending an empty http header.. If anyone knows the answer to this problem / or a polyfill / fix for Safari that would be absolutely amazing!

Comment: I used your code, and looking at the actual network request in the Network tab, the HTTP request to the Dropbox API does have the `Content-Type` header set: `Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. The Angular http library apparently sets that behind the scenes. The Dropbox API requires that not to be set (since there isn't a body to describe), so the solution is to figure out to stop the Angular http library from doing that. I don't know how to offhand unfortunately.

Comment: @Greg appreciate that, I'll have a look into it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `headers.append('Content-Type', null);`?

This seems to work for me:

```
http.post(url, null, new RequestOptions({
  headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': null})
})).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Still the same `Error in call to API function \"files/download\": You provided a non-empty HTTP \"Content-Type\" header (\", text/plain;charset=UTF-8\").` I replicated your code exactly, and added in the `authorization` header to it. For some reason it keeps changing after the request is sent!

Answer (score 1):

```
headers.append('Content-Type', ' ');
```

null doesn't work, an empty string doesn't work, but a *blank space* does work

This was driving me nuts and I could not find a solution - this was a random needle in a haystack hunch and it does work.

Comment: It _does_ work for some browsers, but leads to a `DOM exception 12` on MobileSafari. I got mine to work in the end by creating a standard `XMLHttpRequest` object and doing it the old fashioned way!

Comment: Damn!  I so thought I was going to score an up vote from you for this.  :)       I haven't tested on MobileSafari I'll need it so will probably need to switch to your solution.  This means it must be the angular 2 http library that is adding in the header selectively for *some* browsers - weird.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `headers.append('Content-Type','');` works for me.